# AWS Athena JDBC Jar usage in Datapipeline throwing Java version error

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-athena

I am trying to run sqlactivity in AWS data pipeline using Athena JDBC connection however i get  "UnsupportedClassVersionError" error while running the pipeline.

i got a bit of information from the blog(http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/05/fixing-unsupported-majorminor-version.html) but the part that i am not clear for my case is

Athena Class has Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_60

My system has Java version: 1.8.0_71

so i am not sure why there is a version mismatch.Also i have only JRE installed in my system no JDK. I am completely new to java any help is much appreciated.

Athena JDBC file name: AthenaJDBC41-1.0.1.Jar

JDBC Driver class: com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver

**DataPipeline Error Message:**

ErrorID: ActivityFailed:UnsupportedClassVersionError

ErrorMessage: com/amazonaws/athena/jdbc/AthenaDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Some data pipeline images have java 7 installed by default. Your application is probably runned with the wrong jdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datapipeline is provisioning ec2 instances on your behalf. Default AMI it is using comes with java 1.6 or 1.7. You need to build your own AMI with java 1.8 and specify a reference to your custom AMI  in datapipeline EC2 Resource Properties